# How to get the initiated values in an Angular form

Tags: angular, forms, api, angular-forms

I am creating an update form initializing it's values from an variable, said values do show up on screen but they are not passed when I submit the form.

```
<form #editForm="ngForm" (submit)="onEditSchedule(editForm)">
    <div>
        <input type="text" ngModel name="id" id="id" 
            value="{{Schedule.id}}" hidden>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="start">emplacement de départ</label>
        <input type="text" ngModel name="start" 
            class="form-control" id="start" 
            placeholder="emplacement de départ" 
            value="{{Schedule.start}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="destination">destination</label>
        <input type="email" ngModel name="destination" 
            class="form-control" id="destination" 
            placeholder="destination" 
            value="{{Schedule.destination}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date">date</label>
        <input type="date" ngModel name="date" 
            class="form-control" 
            id="date" 
            value="{{Schedule.date}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="driver">chauffeur</label>
            <select name="driverId" class="form-control" 
                id="driverId" ngModel>
                <option value="" disabled>
                    selectionner le chauffeur
                </option>
                <option *ngFor="let driver of drivers" 
                    [ngValue]="driver.id">
                    {{driver.name}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="provider">fournisseur</label>
            <input type="text" ngModel name="provider" 
                class="form-control" id="provider" 
                placeholder="fournisseur" 
                value="{{Schedule.provider}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="vehicule">vehicule</label>
            <select name="vehiculeId" class="form-control" 
                id="vehiculeId" ngModel>
                <option value="" disabled>
                    selectionner une vehicule
                </option>
                <option *ngFor="let vehicule of vehicules" 
                    [ngValue]="vehicule.id">
                    {{ vehicule.mark }} || {{vehicule.reg_plate}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="edit-schedule-form" 
                class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                annuler
            </button>
            <button [disabled]="editForm.invalid" type="submit" 
                class="btn btn-primary">
                enregistrer
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I mainly need the `id` back to call my `api` but the `json` file is always returning nulls unless I change the initial values.

I retrieve the data like this:

```
onEditSchedule(editForm: NgForm){
    editForm.value.id=this.Schedule.id; //this was just a way I managed to leverage using another variable 
      
    this.subs.add(
        this.comService.editSchedule(editForm.value).subscribe(
            (response)=>{
                location.reload();
            },
            (error: HttpErrorResponse)=>{
                this.message=false;
            }
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: Please share how you are retrieving the values as well

Comment: done! note is that i used this way to retrieve data for my add function and it worked.

Comment: use `[(ngModel)]` if you have preset values.

Comment: adding that generates an error